# Configuration problems with www on a sub domain in CloudFlare without SSL

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain, cloudflare

how to config a domain, a sub domain and a sub sub domain with CloudFlare?

I have `example.com`, `www.example.com`, `subdomain.example.com` and `www.subdomain.example.com`. So far I have tried the following:

Configuration 1:

A Record called example.com pointing to the IP of the server. CNAME called www that points to the domain `example.com`. CNAME called subdomain that points to the domain `example.com`.

The problem here is that `www.subdomain.example.com` does not work and gives me an error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN, everything else works fine.

Configuration 2:

A Record called `example.com` pointing to the IP of the server. CNAME called www that points to the domain `example.com`. A Record called `www.subdomain` that points to the IP of the server.

The problem here is that `subdomain.example.com` does not work and gives me an error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN, however `www.subdomain.example.com` works fine.

What is the right configuration for all of these? I am not interested in SSL. Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: `NXDOMAIN` is a DNS error message telling you that the given domain name does not exist at all, that is it is not published properly on the nameservers that should be authoritative for it (or some parent of it). Besides that, without true names, it will be difficult to help you and if you are using one DNS provider for your need you should probably ask it directly on what is happening. As for "I am not interested in SSL." this is sad, and browsers are going to display pure HTTP more and more as insecure...

Comment: @Patric Mevzek I know, but how to make the config, so I can be able to access the subdomain with www in front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have below records in your DNS -

```
example.com.   A        IP address
www            CNAME    @
subdomain      CNAME    @
www.subdomain  CNAME    @
```

Comment: This solution hasn't solved my issue. But it is the same https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-do-i-create-subdomain/91314